# AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'setNumThreads'

Tags: python, opencv

I have installed Python 3.9 and the pkg opencv-contrib-python 4.6.0.66 (also on another computer, and there all work fine).

What I do is

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\utils\__init__.py in <module>
     ...

---> 96 cv2.setNumThreads(0)  # this is called by ultralytics and throws the error
```

> AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'setNumThreads'

Comment: `$ pip list | grep opencv`

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with opencv-python latest version. I have 4.8.1.78 version that casing issue, install below version of opencv-python works for me.

> pip install opencv-python==4.8.0.74

Comment: 4.9 is the latest release at this time. the issue is most likely *not* due to a specific release, but due to a messed up python installation where multiple opencv packages have been installed side by side.